# Can't open IntelliJ IDEA without root user

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jetbrains-ide

When I am trying to open IntelliJ IDEA using `./idea.sh` in `bin` folder it gives me an error.

But when I try `sudo ./idea.sh` IntelliJ IDEA open without any error.

**Error :**

```
CompileCommand: exclude com/intellij/openapi/vfs/impl/FilePartNodeRoot.trieDescend bool exclude = true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndStartAgent(InstrumentationImpl.java:491)
    at java.instrument/sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:503)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.licel.b.Z@
    at fuck_the_regulations_v320.dH.<clinit>(dH.java)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.licel.b.Z@
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:209)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    ... 7 more
*** java.lang.instrument ASSERTION FAILED ***: "result" with message agent load/premain call failed at src/java.instrument/share/native/libinstrument/JPLISAgent.c line: 422
FATAL ERROR in native method: processing of -javaagent failed, processJavaStart failed
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGABRT (0x6) at pc=0x00007f7211696a7c (sent by kill), pid=26807, tid=26824
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment JBR-17.0.4.1+7-469.62-jcef (17.0.4.1+7) (build 17.0.4.1+7-b469.62)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM JBR-17.0.4.1+7-469.62-jcef (17.0.4.1+7-b469.62, mixed mode, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x96a7c]  pthread_kill+0x12c
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/shehan/Downloads/ideaIU-2022.2.3/idea-IU-222.4345.14/bin/core.26807)
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/shehan/java_error_in_idea_26807.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/JBR
#
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: It looks like a cracked version of the IDE was installed. Try re-installing from the official website https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download to an empty folder

Comment: @EgorKlepikov It's not a cracked version I downloaded it from official web site

Comment: There should be no `-javaagent` in any of the relevant `vmoptions` files. Something is trying to load an agent that's broken.